# Taking Input From User In Array Of String in java

Tags: arrays, arrayofstring

Following is my code snippet and I'm getting on last line on loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] name = new String [5];

    Scanner get = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Name In This Array Of String ");
        [i]name = get.nextLine();  // Here
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is `[i]name`. Where have you defined it?

Comment: What about changing `[i]name` to `name[i]` ?

Comment: Also show your stack trace for error you getting

Comment: Try to change `name[i]` to `[i]name`.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
       String name [] = new String [5];
       
       Scanner get = new Scanner (System.in);
     
        for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Name In This Array Of String ");
            name[i] = get.nextLine(); 
          
        }   //here is the whole code i have changed [i]name to name[i] but did not worked for me .

Comment: Stack trace please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have pre-defined number of inputs you can use Array as you are, to define as run-time you can also use `ArrayList` for that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String [] name = new String [5];
       Scanner get = new Scanner (System.in);
        for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("index = "+i);
            System.out.println("Enter Name In This Array Of String ");
             name[i] = get.nextLine();  // Here
        }
}
```

here is dynamic names example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner get = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean quit=false;
    while(!quit){
         System.out.println("Enter q to quit or Name In This Array Of String ");
         String input = get.nextLine();
         if(input.equals("q")){
           quit=true;
         }else{
           name.add(input);  // Here
         }
     }
  System.out.println("Array Final Values = "+name);
}
```